# nginx is dropping headers Microsoft Edge

Tags: nginx, header, microsoft-edge

On my Ubuntu deployment server Nginx is dropping a custom request header (a token), only if the request is coming from Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer.  Requests coming from Firefox, Chrome or Safari just work fine.

I've done a tcpdump to check the difference between the incoming requests, and the requests look exactly the same (only the User-Agent is different, which seems normal).  All the browsers are sending the token to nginx

Because my header contains an underscore, I have in nginx.conf the line

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

I am logging the header in access log of nginx,and it shows up for all browsers but IE.

Nginx is proxying to a Python Flask application, using gunicorn.  In the Flask application I immediately log the incoming requests and the token is disappeared if the browser is IE.  So apparently nginx drops the header before sending it to gunicorn.

Any advice what can cause this.

Comment: >  All the browsers are sending the token to nginx - How did you confirm that in Edge it is in fact sending the header. nginx doesn't care about User-Agents and if the underscore header shows up for other browser then there's a good chance that Edge isn't actually sending it.

Comment: I did a tcpdump on the server machine, filtering the incoming requests to the url concerned.   I am 100% sure that the request from IE reaches nginx with the token.  If you want I can include the output of the tcpdump

Comment: That's strange then, I can't think of any reason that nginx would operate differently for a different user agent with respect to header processing. Have never encountered that before.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: Do you use a WAF? Maybe a WAF as a service?**

I'd suggest you investigate your full infrastructure/routing topology. There may be load balancers/things in the path that you're not taking into account.

We literally just ran into this exact same issue at my work and your post was the only thing on the internet that sounded like our problem. We ended up figuring out the root cause.

Here's a simplified version of our topology from a DNS routing perspective:

newwebsite.company.com --> Web Application Firewall as a Service (if this fails it fails open) --> Nginx+ (with WAF plugin) --> Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller --> Custom Angular Javascript frontend hosted on Nginx Pod 
legacywebsite.company.com --> F5 load balancer --> Windows IIS Web Server. 

(There was a section of the new site that used the same backend server of the legacy website, and we'd see hidden 500 errors if we used Chrome Developer Tools.

We checked IIS logs and found out headers with underscores were getting stripped from the clients HTTP request b4 they'd get to the backend IIS server/we found out that we had to add `underscores_in_headers on;` to every Nginx Load Balancer in the path and that fixed it! ... or so we thought. It turned out the problem was fixed for every browser except for Internet Explorer / Microsoft Edge. (Your exact scenario)

The crazy thing is if you were on the one url path of the new site that would forward your traffic to the old site's load balancers, then you were going through a crazy amount of load balancers. (The nginx pod that hosted the Angular Javascript frontend would redirect you to the F5 load balancer). We discovered the root cause by process of elimination to get rid of that crazy amount of load balancers in the routing in a way that involved minimal testing. I edited my hostfile for newwebsite.company.com to bypass the WAF as a Service and point straight to the Nginx+ LB acting as a WAF, and it started working/no more 500 errors for IE/Edge.

Our theory is that our WAF as a Service was stripping out a HTTP header that has an underscore (which Win IIS web servers use), and they were only stripping out this HTTP header for Edge/IE. So we've got a ticket with them explaining the situation and directions for reproduceability.